# I need to know if a process is running or not

Tags: process, batch-processing, batch-file, app-id

I need a batch file to continue whenever "My Own Program.exe" shuts down.

I have tried this:

```
@echo off  
:loop  
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq MyOwnProgram.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "MyOwnProgram.exe">NUL  
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" goto done
goto loop  
:done
```

It works fine for single word processes, but not if it were 3 words (Like "My Own Program.exe").

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set /a errorlevel=0
wmic process where (Name ="My Own Program.exe")  get  ProcessId | more +1  | findstr "[1234567890]"
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 (
  echo not running
) else (
   echo running
)
```

I'm not completely sure which of theese corresponds to IMAGENAME in tasklist and condition in wmic query can be changed:

```
Caption
Description
Name
```